# Footnotes misbehaving in report go to front page but behave correctly in other report

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, report, footmisc

I wonder if anyone can advise me as to what is wrong?

I have a LaTeX report where I reference the same footnote more than once on a page in the introduction:

```
documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{abstract}
        This report\ldots
    \end{abstract}

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    
    \part{Introduction and opening remarks}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \section{MySQL}
    MySQL\footnote{\url{http://mysql.com/}.} is a popular RDBMS supported by Oracle\footnote{\url{http://www.oracle.com/}\label{OracleURL}.}.

    \section{NetBeans}
    NetBeans\footnote{\url{https://netbeans.org/}.} is an integrated development environment (IDE) principally for Java, but which supports several other programming languages. and other languages. NetBeans is sponsored by Oracle\footref{OracleURL}.
    \section{Treemap}
    Treemaps are defined by Wikipedia \footnote{\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping}.}.
    
    \chapter{Bakground}
    \chapter{Review} 
            
    \part{Case study one}
    \chapter{Apparatus}
    \chapter{Method} 
    \chapter{Experiment} 
    \chapter{Results}  
    
    \part{Case study two}
    \chapter{Apparatus}
    \chapter{Method}
    \chapter{Experiment}
    \chapter{Results}        
    
    \appendix
    
    \chapter{References}

\end{document}
```

This works correctly. But if I try to add the `usepackage` statements from this report to another, the second report fails to compile because of a

```
 LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotetext  has changed.
           Check if current package is valid.

)

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31 \usepackage
                {footnotebackref}
? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

And even if I reset the `usepackage` statements to:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footmisc}
```

The footnotes of the second report all take me to the report's front page.

Why?

The current second report can't be shown in its entirety but this is very close to what it is like:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report} % Use twoside for alternate page headings.

% \usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
% \usepackage{algorithmicx}
% \usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
% \usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
% \usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
% \usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
% \usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
% \usepackage{soul}

\marginsize{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}

% Tables.
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

% ALGORITHMS. -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@algorithmunruled{\def\@fs@cfont{}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain% Caption style.
    \def\@fs@pre{\kern8pt}
    % \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}% Line at top of algorithm and 2pt gap.
    \def\@fs@post{}
    % \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}% Remove line below `\caption`.
    \def\@fs@mid{\kern8pt}% Line at bottom of algorithm.
    % \def\@fs@mid{}
    \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}% Place caption under algorithm.
\makeatother
\floatstyle{algorithmunruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter}
\makeatother

% GLOSSARY. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist]{glossaries} % Makes a list of abbreviations.
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
% \makeglossaries % This must be run from the command-line: e.g. 'makeglossaries file'
                  % where `file` is the name of the main LaTeX file.
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{Some text\ldots.}

\include{Glossary}
%\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{mcolindex}

% ADD TEXT TO PART PAGE. --------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter

\let\LaTeXStandardPart\part%
\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@noopt}[1]{%
    \unstarredpart@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@opt}[2][]{%
    \cleardoublepage% (For clearing content before.)
    \begingroup%
    \let\newpage\relax%
    \LaTeXStandardPart[#1]{#2}%
    \endgroup%
}

\newcommand{\starredpart}[1]{%
    \LaTeXStandardPart*{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredpart}{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\unstarredpart@@opt}{\unstarredpart@@noopt}%
}

\renewcommand{\part}{%
  \@ifstar{\starredpart}{\unstarredpart}%
}

\begin{document}

    \pagenumbering{roman}

    % Title page.
    \title{\textcolor{red}{** WORKING DRAFT **}}
    \author{Author}

    \begin{abstract}
        This report\ldots
    \end{abstract}

    \tableofcontents

    % Print glossary.
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]
    %\printglossaries%[title={List of abbreviations}]

    % Print algorithms.
    \listofalgorithms
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}

    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \part{Introduction and opening remarks}
    \chapter{Introduction}

    \section{MySQL}
    MySQL\footnote{\url{http://mysql.com/}.} is a popular RDBMS supported by Oracle\footnote{\url{http://www.oracle.com/}\label{OracleURL}.}.

    \section{NetBeans}
    NetBeans\footnote{\url{https://netbeans.org/}.} is an integrated development environment (IDE) principally for Java, but which supports several other programming languages. and other languages. NetBeans is sponsored by Oracle\footref{OracleURL}.
    \section{Treemap}
    Treemaps are defined by Wikipedia \footnote{\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping}.}.

    \chapter{Bakground}
    \chapter{Review}

    \part{Case study one}
    \chapter{Apparatus}
    \chapter{Method}
    \chapter{Experiment}
    \chapter{Results}

    \part{Case study two}
    \chapter{Apparatus}
    \chapter{Method}
    \chapter{Experiment}
    \chapter{Results}

    \appendix

    \chapter{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: We can't know what's in the “other” report, can we?

Comment: I've added something like the second report but it has a lot of other code to do various things.

Comment: It is really not wise to load packages alphabetically, as much as you might like to do so.  Load packages in a conceptually logical order, and note that `hyperref` is a package that should be [among the **last**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/8528) loaded.  (For what it's worth, I tend to group packages into categories like: fonts, (physical) page setup, sectional divisions, language & bibliography, lists & tables,  colours & graphics, misc., personal packages, hyperref & bookmarks.)  See also the [pkgloader](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pkgloader) package.

Comment: Even if I remove `hyperref`, the footnotes still point at the first page. It is irksome. But I take the point about order.

Comment: Please clarify 'remove': in the second .tex file, you have `% \usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}` then `\usepackage{hyperref}` 3 lines later.  That can be the cause of the `Option clash` error you report above(?!) that file if you try to load the package twice.  There are also other loading errors.  `bookmark` loads hyperref, too, which can clash with other packages, such as the graphics-related ones.  (Also: don't load `graphics` and `graphicx` -- just the latter should be fine.)  Really, if you think about and reorganize your preamble, you'll be in better shape overall.

Comment: By remove, I mean literally that I have removed references to `hyperref`. If it is loaded by `bookmark`, surely this is legitimate?

What would be a better way of organising the imports anyway? This is somwething I'm unsure of.

Comment: Of course it is legitimate, but not where *you* are loading it.  Move packages bookmark and hyperref to the end of your list of `\usepackage` declarations (and put bookmark after hyperref).  You cannot load a package multiple times with different options, and this is what is (implicitly) happening in your case.

Comment: Thank you jon. That appears to have solves my problem. Did you want to to post your comment so I can set it as the answer to this post?

Comment: `footmisc` hacks at the footnote code, and so detects (and complains about) changes.  `hyperref` hacks at almost everything, and can't do that reliably if the things have been changed.  apart from all of which (as has been said) you should always place `hyperref` last in the preamble.

Comment: I will be doing that from now on.

Comment: I feel like @Trold already posted an answer close to what I was trying to say.  Perhaps if he makes some minor changes, that one can serve as the answer?

Comment: Over to you @Trold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the option clash warning, the package `bookmark` loads the `hyperref` package with the default set of hyperref package options if it isn't there already. Your bigger footnote problem is the result of setspace changing the definition of `\footnote` after `hyperref` has done its work. If you put `\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}` after setspace but before `bookmarks`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\marginsize{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}

% Tables.
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

% ALGORITHMS. -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@algorithmunruled{\def\@fs@cfont{}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain% Caption style.
    \def\@fs@pre{\kern8pt}
    % \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}% Line at top of algorithm and 2pt gap.
    \def\@fs@post{}
    % \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}% Remove line below `\caption`.
    \def\@fs@mid{\kern8pt}% Line at bottom of algorithm.
    % \def\@fs@mid{}
    \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}% Place caption under algorithm.
\makeatother
\floatstyle{algorithmunruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter}
\makeatother

% GLOSSARY. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist]{glossaries} % Makes a list of abbreviations.
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
% \makeglossaries % This must be run from the command-line: e.g. 'makeglossaries file'
                  % where `file` is the name of the main LaTeX file.
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{Some text\ldots.}

\include{Glossary}
%\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{mcolindex}

% ADD TEXT TO PART PAGE. --------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter

\let\LaTeXStandardPart\part%
\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@noopt}[1]{%
    \unstarredpart@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@opt}[2][]{%
    \cleardoublepage% (For clearing content before.)
    \begingroup%
    \let\newpage\relax%
    \LaTeXStandardPart[#1]{#2}%
    \endgroup%
}

\newcommand{\starredpart}[1]{%
    \LaTeXStandardPart*{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredpart}{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\unstarredpart@@opt}{\unstarredpart@@noopt}%
}

\renewcommand{\part}{%
  \@ifstar{\starredpart}{\unstarredpart}%
}
\begin{document}\pagenumbering{roman}
   \begin{abstract}
        This report\ldots
    \end{abstract}

    \tableofcontents
  \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \part{Introduction and opening remarks}
    \chapter{Introduction}

    \section{MySQL}

    MySQL\footnote{\url{http://mysql.com/}.} is a popular RDBMS supported by Oracle\footnote{\url{http://www.oracle.com/}\label{OracleURL}.}.

    \section{NetBeans}
    NetBeans\footnote{\url{https://netbeans.org/}.} is an integrated development environment (IDE) principally for Java, but which supports several other programming languages. and other languages. NetBeans is sponsored by Oracle\footref{OracleURL}.
    \section{Treemap}
    Treemaps are defined by Wikipedia.\footnote{\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping}.}


\end{document}
```

your report looks like it compiles fine for me.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried this in both reports and neither works properly.

Comment: @MrMorgan Ack. I'm sorry, I must have been reading too hastily. I've updated my answer to one I hope will be more helpful.

Comment: Even if I do change this though, the problem appears unresolved. Everything but the footnotes work.

Comment: That's because I somehow managed to change the order of package uses from the working example on my computer to this answer. I've edited the answer again, this time just copy/pasting the fixed version of your 2nd report into the answer. Hopefully I've not made any more foolish mistakes this time.

Comment: @MrMorgan try to reorder the packages in a more logical order such as Jon suggested you before.

Answer (score 0):

There can be very good reasons to load `hyperref` early.
The following coding works for me.

```
\makeatletter
 \let\HYP@footnotetext\@footnotetext
\makeatother
\usepackage{footmisc}
\makeatletter
 \let\FN@footnotetext\@footnotetext
 \let\H@@footnotetext\FN@footnotetext
 \let\@footnotetext\HYP@footnotetext
\makeatother
```

It works by recreating the expansion of `\@footnotetext` that would occur if `footmisc` were loaded first.