# Package footmisc causes pdfTeX error

Tags: hyperref, footmisc

When using the footmisc package it causes many PdfTeX errors in my thesis:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.1} has beend referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=footnote, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bottom, hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
    @book{SomeSource,
        author = {The Author},
        year = {2015},
        title = {The Title}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some Text.\autocite[][123]{SomeSource}{}
\printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

I found several posts saying, that one should load the `hyperref` package after all other packages, but whether or not I load the package and regardless of the position within the code, the issue remains.

An idea anyone?

BTW: I'm using the versions `hyperref.sty 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX` and `footmisc.sty 2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities`.

Comment: If I use `\usepackage{hyperref}` after `\usepackage[bottom, hang]{footmisc}`, I don't get that warning.

Comment: @Harish: Do you get the warning without adding `hyperref`? Because I just tried it again fearing I made this post for nothing - but still the same behaviour.  Could it be that any other configuration is wrong?

Comment: Without hyperref, no warning! You can try updating or deleting the aux file.

Comment: Deleted the aux file - without effect.

Comment: Did you compile more than once without changinf the document? Normally this messages disappear then.

Comment: In `biblatex`, you can add the option `hyperref=false` (default is `auto`). But I'd just load `hyperref`, and probably  load it with the option `hyperfootnotes=false`.  My guess, however, is that your `Thesis.cls` is doing something it shouldn't, like load `hyperref` at an ill-advised time.

Comment: Neither compiling the docuement repeatedly as propsed by @UlrikeFischer nor adding `hyperref=false` or `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}` as proposed by @jon had any effect.  Is there any way I can look into the `Thesis.cls` file? I searched for it but couldn't locate it on my PC ...

Comment: There is definitely an answer, where `hyperref` is loaded before `footmisc` for whatever reason. See the latest discussion here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203439/footnotes-misbehaving-in-report-go-to-front-page-but-behave-correctly-in-other-r/516359#516359).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your used document class `MastersDoctoralThesis` is that it defined already the call of hyperref.  If you add `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}` you get an option class clash error for package `hyperref`.

Just use `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}` in the line before `\documentclass` (see line 11 of MWE).  With this command you can advice LaTeX to add the given option `hyperfootnotes=false` to package `hyperref` when it is called.

See the corrected MWE (I added the missing packages you left out):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{SomeSource,
  author = {The Author},
  year   = {2015},
  title  = {The Title},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\documentclass[%
  english,
  12pt, 
  oneside
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber, 
  autocite=footnote, 
  citestyle=authoryear-icomp, 
  bibstyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[bottom, hang]{footmisc}
%\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
Some Text.\autocite[][123]{SomeSource}{}

\printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

To test just comment out line 11 and delete the `%` in line 30: your warning returns ...

In the manual of package `footmisc` on page 7 you can read:

> hyperref The hyperref package has ambitions to make hyperlinks from
>   footnote marks to the corresponding footnote body; naturally this
>   causes grief to footmisc, and unfortunately no remedy is currently
>   known. If you use foot- misc, suppress hyperref's hyper-footnotes, by
>   loading it as: \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,...]{hyperref} Further
>   work on the interaction between the two packages is proposed, but not
>   yet scheduled.

Comment: Out of interest, does `hypersetup` in the preamble work? Too lazy to check right now. https://github.com/VelNZ/mastersdoctoralthesislatex/pull/3