# footmisc and hyperref hyperlink failure

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, hyperlink, footmisc

I am using `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` with `hyperref` package. I have loaded the `hyperref` package at last as suggested in many answers. When I click the footnote hyperlink, it takes me to the title page. Also, I get this warning:

> name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

Below is my document preamble. It consists of multiple chapters organized using `subfile`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,   
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=magenta
}

\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\onehalfspacing
```

**Edit:** Here's an MWE. Clicking on the footnote hyperlink takes me back to first page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{doi}
% the above package is creating trouble, but
% I need this to hyperlink DOI's in the
% bibliography, which I manage using natbib
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,   
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=magenta
}

\begin{document}
    First page
    \newpage
    Second page\footnote{Footnote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is not complete or compilable, making it difficult to investigate, but this may be of use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268504/package-footmisc-causes-pdftex-error .

Answer (score 1):

Add the `doi` package after `hyperref` and `footmisc` before `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}    % added last
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,   
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=magenta
}
\begin{document}
    First page
    \newpage
    Second page\footnote{Footnote}
\end{document}
```